# Hide field name and label for Surveyor and show it for Supervisor by Survey123 for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-online, excel, arcgis-survey123, open-data-kit

The scenario is, add new field to xls form that represent percentage (%) of accurate collected by surveyor this field is not visible to the surveyor at the same time this field will be visible to the Supervisor so that validate and evaluation the accurate collected data from the surveyor and type the percentage of data accuracy.

Comment: I would use views on the feature layer that is created. With views you can setup the fields you want visible on feature layer one group may use while the the "parent" feature layer has all the same fields and source. http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D6E1538242B24908B1472154696905D3

Comment: First of all Thank you @Russ, for your reply. i found the solution, we can add "hidden" field into Excel form, this field will be invisible to the surveyor on Survey123, but will be visible to Supervisor on Collector for ArcGIS. The Supervisor will type in this field the percentage of data accuracy for each survey.

Comment: check this image https://ibb.co/iwNmhb

Comment: Cool, that is similar to my second idea where you could set up the popup and have the fields hidden for one map and for the other map have them set as visible.